# The display is wrong when using iTerm2 + screen + emacs on macOS monterey

Tags: macos, emacs, apple-m1, gnu-screen, iterm2

When I use iTerm2 + screen + emacs, the display is something wrong.
For example, underline is set automatically at whitespace even if I don't customize setting.
And character's color is different from what I don't use screen.
The color is pink on screen + emacs, but default color must be blue.
There is a different behavior between using screen and not using screen.
[image]

each information I use as below

- GNU Emacs 28.1
- Screen version 4.09.00 (GNU) 30-Jan-22

And if I checked list-colors-display in this state, colors are not displayed correctly.
[image]

If I don't use screen, the display looks good and list-colors-display is shown correctly.
[image]

And if I use terminal.app instead of iTerm2, it also looks good.
[image]
[image]

Please tell me how to display correct on iTerm2.

Comment: You're not the only one having iTerm2 issues: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/72376/454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the workaround.
If I used emacs 27.1, I don't face this issue.

Answer (score 3):

iTerm2 sets COLORTERM environment variable to truecolor that makes emacs think it can use more colors than 256 - which screen doesn't support. Just unset COLORTERM and things should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

adding below line:

`setenv COLORTERM ""`

to my ~/.screenrc solved the issue for me.